# Centering an ul with rows

Tags: html, css

I have a list with 15 rows. I want to center all the rows to the center - 15 centerd rows.

I tried using `text-align: center` but it didn't work. All the other questions refer to aligning all the list items in 1 row, so it didn't help me.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>title for perspective</h1>
<button>button for perspective</button>
<ul class="tl">
  <li>test list1</li>
  <li>test list2</li>
  <li>test list3</li>
  <li>test list4</li>
  <li>test list5</li>
  <li>test list6</li>
  <li>test list7</li>
  <li>test list8</li>
  <li>test list9</li>
  <li>test list10</li>
  <li>test list11</li>
  <li>test list12</li>
  <li>test list13</li>
  <li>test list14</li>
  <li>test list15</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the list isn't really aligned to the center: it is a bit off to the right.

How can I change it to be truely centered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the padding-left on the UL Tag. Padding-left: 0; should do it im pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the margins and padding from 'ul'

https://jsfiddle.net/Daandeve/4t1asd9j/1/

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The margin and padding on the `<ul>` comes from the default styling that a browser adds to the element. For example if you open Chrome's DevTools and inspect the `<ul>` element you'll see styling like this. The *user agent stylesheet* refers to the browsers default styling. `1em` of margin becomes `16px` as the browser has a `font-size: 16px` and `padding-left:40px` by default.

As the default styling isn't the same between browsers a common technique is to use a reset stylesheet, like [Eric Meyer's Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [Nicolas Gallagher's normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), to reduce these browser inconsistencies.

[image: Default <code><ul></code> styling taken from Chrome's DevTools]

In your case you need to remove the `padding-left` to keep the element to be align horizontally.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/*newly added*/
ul.tl{
  padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>title for perspective</h1>
<button>button for perspective</button>
<ul class="tl">
  <li>test list1</li>
  <li>test list2</li>
  <li>test list3</li>
  <li>test list4</li>
  <li>test list5</li>
  <li>test list6</li>
  <li>test list7</li>
  <li>test list8</li>
  <li>test list9</li>
  <li>test list10</li>
  <li>test list11</li>
  <li>test list12</li>
  <li>test list13</li>
  <li>test list14</li>
  <li>test list15</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problème here is the padding-left. Add a :

`ul{
    padding-left : 0;
}`

to your css and it'll be ok.
I recommend you use the developer console on your browser to understand this kind of problem as you can see down below.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

The UL element has a left padding of 20px. If you remove that the list will be centered.